# C reading a text file separated by spaces with unbounded word size

Tags: c, file, text

I have a text file that contains words (strings) that are separated by spaces. The strings' size aren't bounded, nor is the number of words.
What I need to do is to put all the words from the file in a list. (Assume the list works fine).
I cannot figure out how to overcome the unbounded word size problem. I have tried this :

```
FILE* f1;
f1 = fopen("file1.txt", "rt");
int a = 1;

char c = fgetc(f1);
while (c != ' '){
    c = fgetc(f1);
    a = a + 1;
}
char * word = " ";
fgets(word, a, f1);
printf("%s", word);
fclose(f1);
getchar();
```

My text file looks like this:

```
 this is sparta
```

Notice that that all I was able to get was the first word, and even that I do improperly because I get the error:

```
Access violation writing location 0x00B36860.
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: In case you didn't know (and somewhat piling it on to William's comment) you're also incorrectly assigning the address of a non-mutable memory region to a non-const pointer, then sent it to get overwritten in a `fgets` call.

Comment: The key to this assignment is the word "unbounded." In the C language, you must allocate memory to store things. But, how do you allocate memory to hold something when you don't know its size?  If it's any consolation, generations of C programmers have gotten this wrong and made life easy for crackers and script kiddies. Allocate (malloc) some size of array, keep track of how full it is, and reallocate (realloc) it doubling the size when it gets full. Get it working, then quibble about whether doubling is too aggressive an expansion scheme.

Comment: if you don't expect to handle sizes larger than available memory (you'll need a different strategy then), get file size with `fstat()` first, allocate enough space to read it and read with `fread()` (with exactly the size you got before, just in case anybody appends data while you're reading). This is the safest and fastest way to read files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking suggestions from commenters above, this reallocates memory whenever there is not enough, or apparently just enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
    }

int main() {
    FILE* f1 = NULL;
    char *word = NULL;
    size_t size = 2;
    long fpos = 0;
    char format [32];

    if ((f1 = fopen("file1.txt", "rt")) == NULL)        // open file
        fatal("Failed to open file");
    if ((word = malloc(size)) == NULL)                  // word memory
        fatal("Failed to allocate memory");
    sprintf (format, "%%%us", (unsigned)size-1);        // format for fscanf

    while(fscanf(f1, format, word) == 1) {
        while (strlen(word) >= size-1) {                // is buffer full?
            size *= 2;                                  // double buff size
            printf ("** doubling to %u **\n", (unsigned)size);
            if ((word = realloc(word, size)) == NULL)
                fatal("Failed to reallocate memory");
            sprintf (format, "%%%us", (unsigned)size-1);// new format spec
            fseek(f1, fpos, SEEK_SET);                  // re-read the line
            if (fscanf(f1, format, word) == 0)
                fatal("Failed to re-read file");
        }
        printf ("%s\n", word);
        fpos = ftell(f1);                               // mark file pos
    }

    free(word);
    fclose(f1);
    return(0);
}
```

Program input

```
this   is  sparta
help 30000000000000000000000000000000000000000
me
```

Program output:

```
** doubling to 4 **
** doubling to 8 **
this
is
sparta
help
** doubling to 16 **
** doubling to 32 **
** doubling to 64 **
30000000000000000000000000000000000000000
me
```

Answer (score 2):

Which platform are you on?

If you're using a POSIX-ish platform, then consider using [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines of unbounded size, then one of [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html),
[`strpbrk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strpbrk.html),
[`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html), or (if you are really determined to make your code not reusable)
[`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) to get the boundaries of the words, and finally use
[`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) to create copies of the words.  The pointers returned by `strdup()` will be stored in an array of `char *` managed via `realloc()`.

If you're not on a sufficiently POSIX-ish platform, then you'll need to use `fgets()` with checking to find whether you actually read a whole line — using `realloc()` to allocate more space if your initial line isn't long enough.  Once you've got a line, you can then split it up as before.

You could mess around with POSIX [`getdelim()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) except it only takes a single delimiter and you probably want spaces and newlines to mark the ends of words (and possibly tabs too), which it won't handle.

And, again if you're on a sufficiently modern POSIX system, you can consider using the `m` modifier to [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html):

```
char *word = 0;

while (scanf("%ms", &word) == 1)
    …store word in your list…
```

This is even simpler when it is available.