# How do you properly use the fstat() function and what are its limits?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

So I am very new to C. I have done a lot of programming in Java and am finding it very difficult to learn C.

Currently I am assigned to read in a file from our terminal window, which will contain a list of integers. From this list we must read the values and calculate the average, I believe I have done this correctly.

My only problem is I do not understand how to use the fstat() correctly, I read the man page but am still having a hard time understanding. In my code below, I am wanting to use fstat() to find the size of the file being read so I can then allocate the correct amount of space for my array where I store the values read off the input file. I just need to know the proper usage and syntax of fstat() and from there I believe I can make significant progress. Thanks in advance!

```
    char *infile;
    int fileSize;
    int fd;
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp;
    int sum = 0;
    int average;
    /* enforce proper number of arguments
    */
    if (argc != 1)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Too many arguments.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    infile = argv[1];

    //open file
    fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY);

    //exit if open fails
    assert (fd > -1);

    //find size of file
    fileSize = fstat(fd, blksize_t st_blksize); 

    //fine perfect size for array
    temp =  malloc(temp * sizeof(int));

    //create file of perfect size
    int intArray[temp];

    //scan integers into our array
    for (i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    {
            fscanf(infile, "%d", intArray[i]);
    }
    fclose(fd);

    //add all integers into the array up
    for (j = 0; j < fileSize; j++);
     {
            sum = sum + intArray[j];
     }

    //calculat average
    average = (sum)/fileSize;

    printf("Number of numbers averaged: %d\n Average of numbers: %d\n", fileSize, average);

    if ( close(fd) == -1 )
     {
             fprintf(stderr, "error closing file -- quitting");
             exit(1);
     }

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Note: `malloc(temp * sizeof(int))` temp is indeterminate when used here, and thus invokes *undefined behavior*, so knowing how `fstat` works is *not* your only problem. The assignment to `temp`, an `int` and not a pointer-type, simply adds salt to the wound.

Answer (score 4):

The library function `fstat()` does not return the size of the file, it returns 0 if successful. It informs the file size by filling in the struct passed as an argument.

```
if (fstat( fd, &buf))
    printf("Bad call\n");
else
    printf("File size : %ld\n", buf.st_size);
```

But as @chux (deleted post) answered, it tells you the file size in bytes, not in integers. The function `fscanf()` inputs the data from *text*, so there is no direct correlation between file size, and number of fields.

So unfortunately, in answer to your titled question, using `fstat()` to determine the file size is of no practical use to you. Your secondary implied question is how to allocate enough memory for the array. I posted an answer to that, in a different context where at the outset the array size is unknown. [C reading a text file separated by spaces with unbounded word size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254245/c-reading-a-text-file-separated-by-spaces-with-unbounded-word-size/28255082#28255082)

But here I use a simpler technique - parse the file twice to find out how many textual integers it contains. It then rewinds the file and allocates memory for the array, although, in this example, the array isn't necessary to calculate the sum and average of the values, and the double file parse isn't necessary  either, unless you plan to do more with the values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fil;
    int *array;
    int items = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int avg;
    int value;
    int i;

    if (argc < 2)                                       // check args
        fatal ("No file name supplied");
    if ((fil = fopen (argv[1], "rt")) == NULL)          // open file
        fatal ("Cannot open file");
    while (fscanf(fil, "%d", &value) == 1)              // count ints
        items++;
    printf ("Found %d items\n", items);
    if (items == 0)
        fatal ("No integers found");
    if ((array = malloc(items * sizeof (int))) == NULL) // allocate array
        fatal ("Cannot allocate memory");

    if (fseek (fil, 0, SEEK_SET))                       // rewind file
        fatal ("Cannot rewind file");
    for (i=0; i<items; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fil, "%d", &value) != 1)             // check int read
            fatal ("Cannot read integer");
        array[i] = value;
        sum += value;
    }
    fclose(fil);
    printf ("Sum = %d\n", sum);
    printf ("Avg = %d\n", (sum+items/2) / items);       // allow rounding
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
1 2   3
4 5
6
   -1   -2
```

Program output:

```
Found 8 items
Sum = 18
Avg = 2
```

Comment: @MisterZenious I posted a fuller answer.

Comment: okay. But I would need to give the main() a parameter because I will be passing it a file via the command line through a terminal. So instead of

if ((fil = fopen ("test.txt", "rt")) == NULL)

I would instead need to do 
If((fil = fopen(*arg[1], "rt")) == NULL)

right?

Comment: @MisterZenious almost right - I've amended the answer again to take the filename as a program argument.

Answer (score 3):

You claim to have read the manpage for `fstat()`, which seems at odds with:
`fileSize = fstat(fd, blksize_t st_blksize);`
You need to declare a `struct stat` in the function scope, and pass a pointer to it to `fstat()`:

```
struct stat finfo;
fstat(fd, &finfo);
```

Then you can read the file size from the `struct stat`:

```
off_t filesize = finfo.st_size;
```

I'd also recommend using `size_t` instead of `int` for everything to do with object sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For a file pointer, something like this is needed.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("fileName.png", "rb");

// get file size from file info
struct stat finfo;
if (fstat(fileno(fp), &finfo)) printf("fail");
else off_t pngDataLength = finfo.st_size;
```