# How Can I Scan a File in a Way That Doesn't Discard Newlines

Tags: c

I am relatively new to C programming, but, from what I understand, fscanf skips any whitespace when scanning input for every type beside characters. What other means do I have to scan integers while keeping any newline character that may be attached to them within the file (as I actually want to do something with these newline characters)?

Comment: I think you can use `fgets` to get line with newline character at the end of it.

Comment: `fgets()` is the way to go, but two things might go wrong. The line may be larger than the buffer. You can check if the buffer is full and you then need a fallback strategy, as I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254245/c-reading-a-text-file-separated-by-spaces-with-unbounded-word-size/28255082#28255082 The other problem is the final line in the file might not contain a `newline`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fgets` in the following format:

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

and as it's man page says:

> `fgets()`  reads  in  at  most  one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is
>   stored after the last character in the buffer.

It will read a newline character, however it will stop reading after that and terminate with the null character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fcanf(file,"%[^\n]")` which takes everything up to user hit enter.