# Reading a line from file in C, dynamically

Tags: c, file-io, dynamic, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input_f;

    input_f = fopen("Input.txt", "r"); //Opens the file in read mode.
    if (input_f != NULL)
    {
        char line[2048];

        while( fgets(line, sizeof line, input_f) != NULL )
        {
            //do something
        }
        fclose(input_f); //Close the input file.
    }
    else
    {
        perror("File couldn't opened"); //Will print that file couldn't opened and why.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi. I know I can read line by line with this code in C, but I don't want to limit line size, say like in this code with 2048.

I thought about using malloc, but I don't know the size of the line before I read it, so IMO it cannot be done.

Is there a way to not to limit line size?

This question is just for my curiosity, thank you.

Comment: You can always use `getchar()` + `realloc()`, and there is also `getline()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length

Comment: My answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254245/c-reading-a-text-file-separated-by-spaces-with-unbounded-word-size/28255082#28255082

Comment: Thought: As much as there is a need to not limit size, even a dynamic read-line benefits from having an upper bound to prevent nefarious abuse. Example when reading a line of user input over 1 MB, it may be better to not accept a longer line as it is likely a hacker attack than legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

When you are allocating memory dynamically, you will want to change:

```
char line[2048];
```

to

```
#define MAXL 2048           /* the use of a define will become apparent when you  */
size_t maxl = MAXL;         /* need to check to determine if a realloc is needed  */
char *line = malloc (maxl * sizeof *line);
if (!line)                  /* always check to insure allocation succeeded */
    ...error.. memory allocation failed
```

You read read up to (`maxl -1`) chars or a `newline` (if using `fgetc`, etc..) or read the line and then check whether `line [strlen (line) - 1] == '\n'` to determine whether you read the entire line (if using `fgets`). (POSIX requires all lines terminate with a `newline`) If you read `maxl` characters (`fgetc`) or did not read the newline (`fgets`), then it is a **short read** and more characters remain. Your choice is to `realloc` (generally doubling the size) and try again. To realloc:

```
char *tmp = realloc (line, 2 * maxl)
if (tmp) {
    line = tmp;
    maxl *= 2;
}
```

Note: **never** reallocate using your original pointer (e.g. `line = realloc (line, 2 * maxl)` because if `realloc` fails, the memory is freed and the pointer set to `NULL` and you will lose any data that existed in `line`. Also note that `maxl` is typically doubled each time you `realloc`. However, you are free to choose whatever size increasing scheme you like. (If you are concerned about zeroing all new memory allocated, you can use memset to initialize the newly allocated space to zero/null. Useful in some situations where you want to insure your `line` is always `null-terminated`)

That is the basic dynamic allocation/reallocation scheme. Note you are reading until you read the complete line, so you will need to restructure your loop test. And lastly, since you allocated the memory, you are responsible for freeing the memory when you are done with it. A tool you cannot live without is `valgrind` (or similar memory checker) to confirm you are not leaking memory.

**Tip** if you are reading and want to insure your string is always `null-terminated`, then after allocating your block of memory, zero (`0`) all characters. As mentioned earlier, `memset` is available, but if you choose `calloc` instead of `malloc` it will zero the memory for you. However, on `realloc` the new space is NOT zero'ed either way, so calling `memset` is required regardless of what function originally allocated the block.

**Tip2** Look at the POSIX `getline`. `getline` will handle the allocation/reallocation needed so long as `line` is initialized to `NULL`. `getline` also returns the number of characters actually read dispensing with the need to call `strlen` after `fgets` to determine the same.

Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Do not agree that using "zeroing all new memory allocated" is "useful if wanting to insure your line is always null-terminated".  Checking the return value from `fgets()` is best.  If the return value is not `NULL` (and `size > 0`), then the buffer will always be null character terminated.

Comment: I thought about that. It isn't a one size fits all situations, but how to introduce the new allocater to the concept? I'll think about it and reword. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @chux How's that for a qualification? Feel free to take creative license. The point is to help the OP learn.

Comment: Checking the return value is key.  Should code not check the return value, the state of the buffer is unknown in the case of an IO error.  So pre-zero filling serves no guaranteed behavior.  A useful reason for pre-filling the buffer is with debugging as it may be easier to for coders to observe behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 2 thoughts:

1. An upper bound of allocated memory is reasonable.  The nature of the task should have *some* idea of a maximum line length, be it 80, 1024 or 1 Mbyte.
2. With a clever OS, actual usage of allocated memory may not occur until needed.   See [Why is malloc not "using up" the memory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359)

So let code allocate 1 big buffer to limit pathological cases and let the underlying memory management (re-)allocate real memory as needed.

```
#define N (1000000)
char *buf = malloc(N);
...
while (fgets(buf, N, stdin) != NULL)) {
  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len == N-1) {
    perror("Excessive Long Line");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
free(buf);
```