# Reading a line from text file dynamically

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am trying to learn how to dynamically allocate memory for very long lines when I'm reading a file. I search on here and web and I tried some code.

Firstly, here is my first non-dynamic code:

```
char line[256];
file = fopen(inputFileName, "r");
// Here, of course I checked file is opened or not.
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
     // do some operations
}
// Closing operations
```

This works for me when I reading files. But here is line must be equal or less than 255 characters. So, I want to read for example 300 character length line from file.

I tried following code:

```
size_t maxl = 256;
//char line[256];
char *line = malloc(maxl * sizeof(char));
if(!line){
    printf("Memory not allocated!!\n");
    return -2;
}
file = fopen(inputFileName, "r");

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {

    while(line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\n' || line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\r'){
        char *tmp = realloc (line, 2 * maxl);
        //fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
        if (tmp) {
            line = tmp;
            maxl *= 2;
        }
        else{
            printf("Not enough memory for this line!!\n");
            return -3;
        }
    }
    // do some operations
}
```

I tried to implement answers in this question actually: [Reading a line from file in C, dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500467/reading-a-line-from-file-in-c-dynamically)

But it always enter "Not enough memory" part of the code. So, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you already for your answers and advises.

---

Edit: Code is updated depend on first comments.

---

Edit 2: Code is always read same 3 characters from the file.

Imagine that the file is like:

```
abcdabcdabcd...
```

The `line` variable is always "abc" even after re-allocation operation.

Comment: Your `while` loop will only exit if you read new text from the file inside it, but you don’t.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` Wrong. Are you allocating an array of `char*`? No.

Comment: Also, `line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\0'` will never be true.  You can remove that condition.

Comment: @n.m Changed it to sizeof(char) but it is same again; so it means I have more than one wrong thing :)

Comment: @Ryan Where can I read line again?

Comment: `line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\0'` Useless check, never `false`. It also leads to undefined behaviour if the line is empty (like the rest of your checks).

Comment: Yep, about five or so.

Comment: Done that, too.

Comment: If you have made changes to your code, you may want to update the question.

Comment: Have you fixed the `sizeof(line)` issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some corrections you need to do:

- Change `char *tmp = realloc (line, 2 * maxl);` to `char *tmp = realloc (line, 2 * maxl * sizeof(char);` (just a suggestion!).
- After reallocation of memory, you have to seek back in the file to read complete string. For instance, `fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);` will seek to the beginning of the file `inputFileName`.
- `sizeof(line)` will always be a **constant** value as you are computing the size of a character pointer, not the string length. So, change `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {` to `while (fgets(line, maxl, file)) {`.
- Move the commented line `//fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);` inside the `if (tmp)` block because you would want to read the string from file again after reallocation.
- The expression `line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\n' || line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\r'` is logically incorrect. You may want to enter the loop only if the last character of the `line` is neither `'\n'` nor `'\r'`. So you must use a `&&` there instead of `||`.

Here is the modified code:

```
size_t maxl = 256;
//char line[256];
char *line = malloc(maxl * sizeof(char));
if(!line){
    printf("Memory not allocated!!\n");
    return -2;
}
file = fopen(inputFileName, "r");

while (fgets(line, maxl, file)) {

    while(line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\n' && line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\r'){
        char *tmp = realloc (line, 2 * maxl * sizeof(char));

        fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);          //or wherever you want to seek to
        if (tmp) {
            line = tmp;
            maxl *= 2;
            fgets(line, maxl, file);
        }
        else{
            printf("Not enough memory for this line!!\n");
            return -3;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",line);     //just to check
}
```

The problems in your code were:

- You were reading only a few characters from the file because you were reading `sizeof(line)` number of characters only and not `maxl` number of characters.
- You may want to seek back some bytes to read the whole string again, but that is up to you.
- Read a string again from the file after reallocation only if the reallocation is successful (`if(tmp)`).

Now, why that `Not enough memory..` was printing?

It was because your loop was running multiple times and the reallocated memory size (`maxl` value) was increasing like 256, 512, 1024, 2048, ..., 65536, ...

When this size becomes large enough for the compiler to deny reallocation, you had that error string printed. If you like, try to debug your version of the code or print the value of `maxl` in each iteration of inner `while` loop.

Comment: Hey, skrtbhtngr. Thanks for your explanation, it is very clear and informative. But after correcting these lines, I am again get "Not enough memory" message

Comment: I tried out the modified code, it is working fine. Can you check your `maxl` value in each iteration?

Comment: Starts from 256 and increasing like 512,1024,... until there are no memory as you mentioned in your answer

Comment: Yes, it is exactly same

Comment: Try to print the value of `line` in each iteration of inner while loop.

Comment: Assume that our input's length is 269 characters. Before re-allocation it gets 255 characters correctly. After that it prints all line (269) characters. Then on every iteration it prints that all line until "Not enough memory" part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128560/discussion-between-skrtbhtngr-and-pilkington).

Comment: @pilkington this repeating the same lines how to clear it ?