# Read from stdin with fgets, bug if input is greater than size

Tags: c

I'm creating a command line application with a prompt. It works fine as long as the input fits inside the buffer, but when the input is larger I get some weird behavior. Below is a simplified minimal example which has the same bug.

```
int main()
{
    for (;;) {
        const int size = 8;
        char str[size];

        printf("> ");
        fgets(str, size, stdin);

        toupper_str(str);
        printf("Result: %s\n", str);
    }
}
```

It works fine if the input is in smaller than `size`.

```
> asdf
Result: ASDF
>
```

When the input is larger, the portion of the input in range is processed, and in the next loop iteration, the rest of the given input is immediately returned from `fgets`. This leads to that portion of the input also being processed and some weird output.

```
> asdfghjk
Result: ASDFGHJ
> Result: K

>
```

I can see if the input is larger than or equal to size by comparing the last character to a newline. `fgets` retains the newline as long as it fits.

```
fgets(str, size, stdin);
if (str[strlen(str) - 1] != '\n') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input too long\n");
}
```

When this is detected, how do I stop it from reading the rest of the too long input on the next iteration?

I've seen similar questions on here, but none that ask the same question.

Comment: That is how `fgets` works. It does *not* discard the rest of the input, and your code should take that into account. If there is no `newline` at the end, the line was longer (except the last line of the file). Although if you missed the length by 1, the next input might contain *only* a `newline`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The question is *how* to take it into account. It is obviously how `fgets` work.

Comment: You have not said whether you want to discard the rest of the too-long input or consider it. Former: if `fgets` string does not terminate with a `newline` (before the `nul` of course) keep reading with `getchar` until `newline` or `EOF`. Latter: use allocated buffers and `realloc` if the input did not contain a final `newline`. Here in a different question is a way to use the technique. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254245/c-reading-a-text-file-separated-by-spaces-with-unbounded-word-size/28255082#28255082

Comment: I think your question is better stated as how to process *all* the input than find ways to dump input you cannot handle: that leads to GIGO.

Comment: @WeatherVane As you can see in the provided code, the buffer is allocated on the stack and can as such not be `realloc`ed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sometimes you do not want a string over a certain length. But in most cases you are right, reading the whole input would be the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: if you do know the max size a line can have in the input file, you could allocate a proper buffer and read each whole line into it with fgets. Then you truncate the buffer to the relevant portion of the string (e.g. 7 chars)

Comment: @Pynchia Yes, but that would a) make code more complex than it needs to be and b) use more memory than needed.

Comment: I think the code would be simpler and the buffer would be recycled on each line, but yes, life is often a trade-off between performance, cost, size, elegance, etc. :)

Comment: Hej, Anything more needed to answer this post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how do I stop it from reading the rest of the too long input on the next iteration?

Code needs to 1) detect if input is "too long" 2) consume the additional input.

`fgets()` will not overfill it buffer.  If it does fill the buffer, the last `char` in the buffer is `'\0'`.  So set that to non-`'\0'` before reading.  Then code knows if the entire buffer was filled.  Then check if the preceding `char` was a `'\n'`.  If it is not an end-of-line, additional `char` *may* exist in `stdin`

```
char str[100];  // Insure buffer is at least size 2
for (;;) {
  str[sizeof str - 1] = `x`;
  if (fgets(str, size, stdin) == NULL) {
    // No more to read or IO error
    break;
  }
  int extra_data_found = 0;
  if (str[sizeof str - 1] == '\0' && str[sizeof str - 2] != '\n') {
    // Cope with potential extra data in `stdin`: read and toss
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      extra_data_found = 1;
    }
  }
  // Use `str` as needed, noting if additional unsaved data found
  foo(str, extra_data_found);
}
```

Note: on a file error, `fgets()` returns `NULL` and the contents of `str` are undefined.

Note: Instead of `str[sizeof str - 1] == '\0'`, code could use `strlen(str) == sizeof str - 1`.  This gets fooled should `fgets()` read a null character `'\0'`.

Corner cases:
1. Typical `str` will be up to 98 `char` and then `'\n'` and `'\0'`.  Is it OK is the *last* `str` is 99 `char` and then `'\0'`?
2. If #1 is OK, then may a typical `str` have 99 `char` and then `'\0'`?

Answer (score 3):

When the input is too long, you need to read the remaining characters on stdin before continuing with the next iteration of the loop.

```
if (fgets(str, size, stdin) == NULL) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        return 0;
    else {
        perror("Could not read from stdin");
        exit(1);
    }
}
else if (strchr(str, '\n') == NULL) {
    int c;
    while((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    fprintf(stderr, "Input too long\n");
}
```

If you are on a POSIX system like OS X or Linux there is already the `getline` function that reads an arbitrary length newline terminated string from a stream. You can also find many free/open source versions of this function online.

Comment: `if (!feof(stdin)) ... "Could not read from stdin"... ` is dubious.  Commonly, by user control or through re-directed input, `stdin` will supply input for a while and then `feof(stdin)` will be true.  It is not "Could not read from stdin", it is more like "no more to read".

Comment: @chux `fgets` can return `NULL` in two cases: if end of file is met or if an error occurred. If it returned `NULL` and it's not end of file, it must be an error, thus "Could not read from stdin". The code should handle the case where `feof(stdin)` is true too though, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @jacwah Agree `fgets()` returns `NULL` in 2 cases, but are there more?  Consider pathological case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388620/is-fgets-returning-null-with-a-short-bufffer-compliant  (Not that you need to change answer because of this)

Comment: @chux Good find! Did not think of this.